# Why is my cat losing her hair and not wanting to use the litter boxes?

Tags: cats, health

My cat is 9 yrs old, and over the past year she has started losing hair around her back legs and tail. Initially, I thought it may have been due to fleas, so I got her on a once a month flea tablet that works very well. However, her hair still hasn't been coming back and now she will not use any of the litter boxes. We have not changed the type of litter we use or any of her food, so I am at a loss. We have other cats and dogs and none of them show any signs of illness or behaviors like she has. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you veterinarian have to say about the condition?

Comment: Please take her to a vet. We aren't vets, and even if we were, we wouldn't be able to diagnose an animal without seeing it.

Answer (score 4):

As someone who has similar issues with my own cat, this kind of behavior around the litter box always ends with the same results... my cat has a UTI.

If your cat is acting strange she is trying to tell you something, "Take me to the vet!"

The hairless hindquarters in my experience is usually allergy related, not necessarily like a rash, but an internal allergic reaction that usually requires regular treatment.

But only your vet can tell you for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try something first before a vet visit, you could try a different brand of litter.

Consider also that missing hair could be the result of licking.  Do some careful observing to see if that's happening.  This could be helpful information if you do end up taking your cat to the vet for this problem.

Comment: I've see hairless patches from excessive grooming in several cats. In one it was a stress response, like a human chewing fingernails. In the other it seems to have been a dietary allergy; i stopped feeding her fish and she's been fine.

Answer (score 0):

Changes such as these in both appearance and behavior are very often a sight of a heakth problem.

Best advice is to have a vet check her out.

Things like this can be minor but they can also be major. Things can run from allergies to diabetes to renal failure.

Have her checked out.